# Find the equation of the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is my first post to math.stackexchange - hope you guys can help me.  I'm preparing for a linear algebra exam this week, and would like to check that my methods are correct.

The question asked in the paper is

> Find an equation of the plane containing the point $(1, 1, -1)$ and perpendicular to the line through the points $(2, 0, 1)$ and $(-1, 1, 0)$.

My method is:

1. Solve for the normal vector:

   $\mathbf{n} = 
   \left(\begin{matrix}
     2 - (-1)\\
     0 - 1\\
     1 - 0
    \end{matrix}\right) = (3, -1, 1)^T$
2. Using the Dot Product, solve the equation for the plane:

   $P = (1, 1, -1)$

   $P_x = (x, y, z)$

   $\mathbf{n}\cdot(P_x-P) = 0$

   $\mathbf{n}\cdot(x-1, y-1, z+1) = 0$

   $3(x-1) - (y-1) + (z+1) = 0$

   $3x - 3 - y + 1 + z + 1 = 0$

   $3x - y + z = 1$

Is this correct?  I'm a bit thrown by the simplicity of the problem, and subsequent questions that build on this equation.

Comment: Welcome to mathSE!! yes is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response - really appreciate the feedback.